# Wordpress Custom Style Editor

Tags: css, wordpress, styles, editor

I would like to custom my WYSIWYG Editor on Wordpress.

Currently, I've added the following code to my *functions.php* file, and it's working on the Wordpress back office.

```
function custom_editor_styles() {
    add_editor_style('editor-styles.css');
}

add_action('init', 'custom_editor_styles');
```

I can see my custom css on the back office, but it isn't working on the front office.

Anyone have a solution to display the custom css ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_custom_css' );

function my_custom_css() {

    if(!is_admin())
    wp_enqueue_style( 'my-custom-css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'editor-styles.css', [], null,'all' );
}
```

Try this code snippet

Comment: @WDCreativ Updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution.

In fact, I didn't know that the *style-editor.css* file was used only to see a preview on the back office.

I was thinking that the *style-editor.css* served to custom the css in front too. But in fact, it is necessary to copy and past the code in the main css file.

So, my first code version is working.